# Silly nginx rewrite issue - infinate loop

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm totally baffled with this one. Its probably something silly, and I'm missing it after along day! Anyway, I have this rewrite rule setup in my nginx config for the site:

```
location / {
    root   /srv/www/site.co.uk/www;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    rewrite ^/(.*)/index.html$ http://site.co.uk/$1/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/index.html$ http://site.co.uk/ permanent;
}
```

When I go to:

- http://www.example.com/index.html
- http://www.example.com/foo/index.html

..then it correctly sends to:

- http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/foo/

If I comment those 2 rewrite rules out, restart nginx, then retry... the page loads fine!

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Maybe I'm just being blind!

Comment: It's not clear what the problem you're having is? When are you seeing the infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have constructed a rewrite loop.

The `index` directive effectively generates an internal rewrite to `/index.html` whenever a URL with a trailing `/` is presented.

One way to break the loop is to only apply your `rewrite` rules when the external URL contains `index.html`. The variable `$request_uri` contains the external URL and can be tested using an `if` directive. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) regarding `if`.

```
if ($request_uri ~* "/index\.html(?|$)") {
    rewrite ^(.*/)index\.html$ $scheme://$server_name$1 permanent;
}
location / {
    root   /srv/www/site.co.uk/www;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```